# Trouble creating button to delete all products from a database for one user in Symfony

Tags: php, database, symfony

Took a few snippets from the different areas I worked on the code. I tried copying and altering the code to delete one product. Currently there is no response when clicking the delete all button I created.

**Service**

```
public function deleteAllProductsByVendorId($vendorId)
{
    $this->productRepository->deleteAllProductsByVendorId($vendorId);
}
```

**Repository**

```
public function deleteAllProductsByVendorId($vendorId)
{
    // @Todo: revisit this at a later date and determine if the vendor id is actually required
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->delete("Thinkfasttoys\Mapwatch\Entity\Product","p")
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('p.vendor_id', ':vendor_id'))
        ->setParameter(':vendor_id', $vendorId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

**Controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/vendor/{vendorId}/product/deleteAll", name="admin_vendor_product_delete_all_ajax", defaults={"vendorId"=""})
 * @Route("/admin/vendor/{vendorId}/product/deleteAll", name="admin_vendor_product_delete_all"))
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_ADMIN")
 */
public function deleteAllProductForVendorAction($vendorId)
{
    $request = $this->container->get('request');

    if ($id == '') {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice-error', 'Vendor Id must be supplied!');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_vendors_list'));
    }

    $vendorService = $this->get('Thinkfasttoys.MapWatch.Vendors');

    $vendor = $vendorService->getProfileById($id);

    if (!$vendor) {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice-error', 'Vendor does not exist!');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_vendors_list'));
    }

    $user = $vendor->getUser();

    if (!$user) {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice-error', 'User for this Vendor does not exist!');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_vendors_list'));
    }

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $productService = $this->get('Thinkfasttoys.MapWatch.Products');

        $productService->deleteAllProductsByVendorId($vendorId);

        return new Response(json_encode(array('status' => 'ok')),200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));//make sure it has the correct content type
    } else {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_vendor_products_edit', array('id' => $vendorId)));
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#importProductsModal" id="importProducts" class="btn btn-danger">Import Products</a>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#productModal" id="addProduct" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Add New Product</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id="deleteall">Delete All</a>
</div>
```

**Created Var deletePathAll**

```
var vendorId = {{ vendorId }};
var getPath = '{{ path('admin_vendor_product_get_ajax', { id: vendorId } ) }}';
var editPath = '{{ path('admin_vendor_product_edit', { id: vendorId } ) }}';
var deletePath = '{{ path('admin_vendor_product_delete_ajax', { id: vendorId } ) }}';
var deletePathAll = '{{ path('admin_vendor_product_delete_all_ajax', { vendorId: vendorId } ) }}';
```

**JS**

```
$('#deleteall').on('click', 'table#products', function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var aData = $('#products').dataTable().fnGetData(aPos);

row.find('a').attr('disabled', true);

var rowId = aData['id'];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: deletePathAll,
    success: function(data) {
        oTable.fnReloadAjax();
    },
    error: function(data) {
        row.find('a').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: First step try your delete action without Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your Product entity doesn't have the property vendor_id but vendor.

In this case this should correct the issue

```
->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('p.vendor_id', ':vendor_id'))
```

should be replaced with

```
->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('p.vendor', ':vendor_id'))
```